# ASP.NET MVC DateTime format dynamically

Tags: asp.net-mvc, datetime, format

I am looking for a way to dynamically specify the format of my model DateTime fields in the view. I need these to be editable (meaning I want changes to them to be properly bound to model on postback). I am not worried about validation as I will be using a jquery datepicker control on the resulting textboxes.

So far all I have found is a way of setting the format in data annotations in the model - which is way too static and restricting (unless there is also a way to modify data annotations at runtime?). Have also found guides for making templates for DateTime, but that is also static. Found some ways to format the fields in the view for "display only" requirements that won't post back changes.

So far the only thing I have come up is having a separate string field for each DateTime field in all my models, do conversion in controllers manually before displaying only the string fields, and then convert them back. Before I embark on his messy approach, does anyone have any suggestions for an easier/cleaner way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could technically write your own Annotation that will give you the dynamic format depending on your wants.

These are evaluated at runtime so depending on what you want to return you can do it then.

I am currently using attributes to return very specific data for specific uses.

Comment: Upon reading up on them - yes you are right. Though it looks like to me to be more work then the string duplicates. Still, thank you for the alternative.